# Get a key from an array inside an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var Game1 = ["name", "image", "genre"]
var Game2 = ["name2", "image2", "genre2"]
var Game3 = ["name3", "image3", "genre3"]

var games = [Game1, Game2, Game3]
```

I want to store some arrays inside an other array, as shown above, and I want to be able to show all of the names of the arrays. So here, I would like to get Game1[0], Game2[0] and Game3[0], but I want to get them from the games array.
How would I go about doing this?
I was thinking of using a for loop over games, but I'm not sure how to get the 0th element from the arrays inside the games array.
I'm quite new to javascript, which is why I could not figure this out.

Comment: Would `games[0]` not suffice? That would give you the `Game1` array.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: Side note: `Game1` 2 and 3 don't look like they should be arrays. They look like they should be non-array objects with named properties `name`, `image`, and `genre`, e.g.: `var game1 = {name: "...", image: "...", genre: "..."};`

Answer (score 0):

You can access like below.

```
 games[0][0] - will gives you the Game1[0] value
 games[1][0] - will gives you the Game2[0] value
 games[2][0] - will gives you the Game3[0] value
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/btt6wbwh/)